# Dino2 for classification has wrong number of labels

Tags: pytorch, huggingface-transformers, huggingface, imagenet, vision-transformer

I am encountering an issue when using the Dinov2ForImageClassification model from the Hugging Face Transformers library, as outlined in the documentation [here](https://huggingface.co/docs/transformers/main/model_doc/dinov2#transformers.Dinov2ForImageClassification). Despite following the provided code example and using the latest Transformers version, the resulting model is performing binary classification instead of the expected ImageNet 1000-way classification. Specifically, the length of the logits returned by the model (`logits`) is 2, whereas it should be 1000 for ImageNet classification.

Here is my code:

```
from transformers import AutoImageProcessor, Dinov2ForImageClassification
import torch
from datasets import load_dataset

# Load a sample image dataset (in this case, "huggingface/cats-image")
dataset = load_dataset("huggingface/cats-image")
image = dataset["test"]["image"][0]

# Load the image processor and the Dinov2ForImageClassification model
image_processor = AutoImageProcessor.from_pretrained("facebook/dinov2-base")
model = Dinov2ForImageClassification.from_pretrained("facebook/dinov2-base")

# Prepare the input and obtain logits
inputs = image_processor(image, return_tensors="pt")
with torch.no_grad():
    logits = model(**inputs).logits

# The expected number of labels for ImageNet classification should be 1000
predicted_label = logits.argmax(-1).item()
```

However, I encounter the following error:

csharpCopy code

```
Some weights of Dinov2ForImageClassification were not initialized from the model checkpoint at facebook/dinov2-base and are newly initialized: ['classifier.bias', 'classifier.weight']
You should probably TRAIN this model on a down-stream task to be able to use it for predictions and inference.
```

Additionally, the shape of `logits` is `torch.Size([1, 2])`, indicating that the model has only 2 labels instead of the expected 1000 as specified by `model.num_labels`.

I'm seeking guidance on how to correctly use Dinov2ForImageClassification for ImageNet 1000-way classification as mentioned in the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

I tested your code and you are right. There seems to be a bug related to the `DinoV2` model. I also tried using `AutoModelForImageClassification` instead of directly opting for Dino explicitly like in your code, but it yielded the same output(2 labels).

I changed the code to load the `SwinTransformer` model:

```
from transformers import AutoImageProcessor, AutoModelForImageClassification
import torch
from datasets import load_dataset

# Load a sample image dataset (in this case, "huggingface/cats-image")
dataset = load_dataset("huggingface/cats-image")
image = dataset["test"]["image"][0]

# Load the image processor and the Dinov2ForImageClassification model
image_processor = AutoImageProcessor.from_pretrained("microsoft/swin-tiny-patch4-window7-224")
model = AutoModelForImageClassification.from_pretrained("microsoft/swin-tiny-patch4-window7-224")

# Prepare the input and obtain logits
inputs = image_processor(image, return_tensors="pt")
with torch.no_grad():
    outputs = model(**inputs).logits

print(len(outputs[0]))
```

> Could not find image processor class in the image processor config or
> the model config. Loading based on pattern matching with the model's
> feature extractor configuration. 1000

Indeed it prints `1000`.

My suggestion is to open a bug report on HuggingFace's official github.

However, if you have to finetune it on your own data, I am pretty sure you will not encounter any errors anymore given the fine-tuning process; meanwhile you can opt for other models if it suits your purpose.